# Add folder column to Reports search results

Tags: search-layout

Is it possible to add Folder column to search results for Reports, by default only Report Name and Description are showing.

p.s. the search in question is the global search that searches all the records and groups them by record type on the left side (SF lightning).

Edit: I have added this picture to clarify the question:

[image]

Comment: Only report folders that you have permission to access will return results from that kind of query/report. Private folders won't be included.

Comment: Security is not an issue here. For custom objects I can easily edit this columns returned in a search, but Report record does not seem like it can be edited.

Comment: Still no ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're in Lightning, it appears you'll want to see [How Is Search Different Between Lightning Experience, Salesforce Classic, and Salesforce1?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_desktop_mobile_comp.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

In particular, **with Lightning:**

> You see Top Results, which lists the top results for most frequently used objects. Change the object to see more results.
>
> Results are sorted by relevance.

**In Classic:**

> You see the top 5 records for each of your most recently used objects.
>
> Results are **grouped by object** and sorted by relevance.

---

Other links of interest:

- [How to locate dashboards and reports hidden in personal folders?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=How-to-locate-dashboards-and-reports-hidden-in-personal-folders&language=en_US&type=1)
- [Access to Report Folders](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=access_report_folders.htm&type=0)
- [Searchable Fields by Object in Salesforce Classic.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_cex.htm&type=0&language=en_US)
- [Lightning Experience Roadmap](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_roadmap.htm&language=en_US&type=0)
- [Notes on Search Layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_searchlayout_notes.htm&type=0)
- [Metatadata API - Folder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_folder.htm)

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question, but thanks anyways. I have already search all of this before. I came here as a last resort. The question is simple and it needs a yes or no answer. And my guess is that the answer is No.

Comment: It does answer your question. In Lightning, you cannot do this. All results are in a single column by object. In Classic, results are grouped by object and you could do what you're asking.